# trouble linking to a tab with jquery

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, tabs, href

im having trouble linking to a tab i have in my html either from within the same document or outside it...

here is the js code...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.tabs a').click(function(){
    switch_tabs($(this));
});

switch_tabs($('.defaulttab'));
 });

 function switch_tabs(obj)
{
  $('.tab-content').hide();
  $('.tabs a').removeClass("selected");
  var id = obj.attr("rel");

  $('#'+id).show();
  obj.addClass("selected");
 }
```

and here is the way they are structured in the document...

```
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#" rel="tabs2">Quickbooks</a></li>
```

that code makes a 'button' pulls up this tab

```
 <div class="tab-content" id="tabs2">
  <p>QuickBooks</p>
 </div>
```

what i want to do is use a href like this

```
   <a href="quickbooks.html#tabs2">Quickbooks</a>
```

and have it pull up the page and the associated tab...  im having quite a bit of trouble...
any suggestions?

Comment: Use a href like what? -->what i want to do is use a href like this ""

Answer (score 0):

Check the `location.hash` property in your `ready` handler:

```
if (location.hash.length > 1) {
    var tab = $('a[rel="' + location.hash.substring(1) + '"]');
    if (tab.length)
        switch_tabs(tab);
}
```

Comment: @n0t In your ready handler. If the hash is empty or invalid, you could then fall back to `switch_tabs($('.defaulttab')`.